# Getting Text from Div C# StreamReader

Tags: c#, html, text-files, streamreader

I'm trying to get a specific div from a textfile filled with div's.
I'm using streamreader to get into the file, but I don't know how to get the complete div.
After getting the div I'm gonna turn each line into a string, which will be added to a list.
The textfile is as follows:

```
<div id="#SMINLANGUAGE1 ">
English
Hello.
This is a Test
Test 23
</div>
<div id="#SMINLANGUAGE2 ">
Dutch
Hallo.
Dit is een Test
Test 29
</div>
<div id="#SMINLANGUAGE3 ">
Spanish
Hola.
Esto es una Prueba.
Prueba 86
</div>
```

List for English would be:

```
 Index 0: English
 Index 1: Hello.
 Index 2: This is a Test
 Index 3: Test23
```

Comment: I have used the CsQuery to accomplish this.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22092208/parsing-html-with-csquery

Answer (score 1):

First you need to install `HtmlAgilityPack` to parse HTML:

```
Install-Package HtmlAgilityPack
```

Then by selecting `//div` path, we can extract all of the available DIVs form the HTML content:

```
    var doc = new HtmlDocument
    {
        OptionOutputAsXml = true,
        OptionCheckSyntax = true,
        OptionFixNestedTags = true,
        OptionAutoCloseOnEnd = true,
        OptionDefaultStreamEncoding = Encoding.UTF8
    };
    doc.LoadHtml(htmlContent);

    var results = new List<string[]>();
    foreach (var node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div"))
    {
        var divContent = node.InnerText;
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(divContent))
            continue;

        var lines = divContent.Trim().Split(new[] { '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        results.Add(lines);
    }
```