# Get source from a Website with anchor tag

Tags: c#, downloadstring

I play on a private WoW server and i want to get the player names from the Website.

I tried with the `DownloadString` method but it doesn't works.

Here is the [link: `/information#allrealm`](https://tauriwow.com/information#allrealm) but I  can get the source just from [/information](https://tauriwow.com/information).
It does not consider the **#allrealm** tag. So I can't get the player names.

How can I get the source code from the website using the `#allrealm` tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The details of the users are loaded by an Ajax call as you can see if you open the Developer Tools of your webbrowser:

[image: developer tools showing ajax calls]

You need to fed the `DownloadString` method with that XHR url:

```
using(var wc = new WebClient())
{
    wc.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    var all = wc.DownloadString("https://tauriwow.com/allrealm/ajax");
    Console.WriteLine(all);
}
```

The content you get is html, so you have to do the parsing of that by yourself, maybe using a library like [`CsQuery`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22092208/parsing-html-with-csquery)

When you run above snippet this is what you get:

> ```
> <div class="lft realmBox realmBoxFirsts">
>     <div class="realmTitle">
>         <div class="subtitle"><div class="lft"><b>&raquo;</b></div><div class="lft subtitle2">Tauri WoW Server</div><div class="rgt realmType">RPPvP</div></div>
>     </div>
>         <div class="realmStats"><a href="/allrealm/12">Detailed statistics</a></div>
>         <div class="realmDetails">
>                                             1) Acélember (<font style="color: lightblue;">20</font>)<br />2) Adjádékát (<font style="color: lightblue;">1</font>)<br />3) Adoresta
> ```